# Codeigniter rest server implementation error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

I am using codeigniter rest ful api service for my website
and using json response. We implemented it with ajax. The code is perfectly working in localhost but it is not working in online. It is showing a 200 response but json data is not parsing in ajax the below is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>news/news.json",
        type: "POST",
        data: "",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var news_title, news_id, new_image;
            var json = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
            var str2;
            $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
                news_title = obj.news_title_en;
                news_id = obj.news_id;
                new_image = obj.news_image_en;
                str2 = "";
                str2 += '<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>news_detail/' + news_id + '">';
                if (new_image != '') {
                    str2 += '<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/uploads/news/small/' + new_image + '" alt="' + news_title + '" /><span style="width:187px;font-size:13px;">' + news_title.substring(0, 22) + '</span>';
                } else {
                    str2 += '<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/no-image.jpg" alt="' + news_title + '" /><span style="width:187px;font-size:13px;">' + news_title.substring(0, 22) + '</span>';
                }
                str2 += '</a>';
                $('#news').append(str2);
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#news').append('No News to display');
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>events/events.json",
        type: "POST",
        data: "",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var events_id, events_title_en, events_image_en;
            var json = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
            var str3;
            $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
                events_title = obj.events_title_en;
                events_id = obj.events_id;
                events_image = obj.events_image_en;
                str3 = "";
                str3 = '<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>events_detail/' + events_id + '">';
                if (obj.events_image_en != '') {
                    str3 += '<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/uploads/events/small/' + events_image + '" alt="' + events_title + '" /><span  style="width:187px;">' + events_title.substring(0, 22) + '</span>';
                } else {
                    str3 += '<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/no-image.jpg" alt="' + events_title + '" /><span style="width:187px;">' + events_title.substring(0, 22) + '</span>';
                }
                str3 += '';
                $('#events').append(str3);
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#events').append('No Events to display');
        }
    });
});
```

For the first section news it is working perfectly fine in online and in local both are working fine. Please let me know what is the issue

The below is my controller code

```
 public function events_post($id="")

    $data=array();  
    $post=$this->input->post();                
    $id=$post['id'];
    $session_data = $this->session->all_userdata();         
    $this -> load -> model('events_model', 'Events');   
    $data=$this->Events->getEvents($id);                

    $this->response($data);



public function events_detail_get($id="")

    $data=array();
    $session_data = $this->session->all_userdata(); 
    $data['page_name']='events';
    $this->load->view($this->site_lang.'/layouts/header-'.$this->site_lang.'.php',$data);       
    $this->load->view($this->site_lang.'/events-detail-'.$this->site_lang.'.php',$data);        
$this->load->view($this->site_lang.'/layouts/footer-'.$this->site_lang.'.php',$data);
```

Comment: Use dataType: "json" in ajax configuration to get data in json format

Comment: i have done it before but it wasn't working , you see the code for news working perfectly without dataType:json

Comment: Use console.log(data); in success callback to check what response you get from server and post response here